# Wrong app in W10 for Android phone. Can I fix with a registry key?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, android, phone

When I first plugged in my new phone, I accidentally clicked the box that makes Media Player start ever time the phone is plugged in. I want Photo. Have been through all the settings I can find. So have Microsoft Help. Is there a registry key that saves this? My old phone opens the correct app.

Answer (score 1):

Open control panel, click on Hardware and Sound (the whole section), then "Autoplay" (AFAIK it has that name in the english version of Windows, in spanish says "Reproducción Automática")

[image: Autoplay]

There should be separated sections for both your old phone and the new one, there you can choose what happens

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked. I don't understand why the MS assistant did not know something that turned out to be so simple. Will feed back to them.